# How to setup Visual Studio 2022 .NET 7.0 to create a Notification Listener

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2022, notification-listener

How to setup Visual Studio 2022 .NET 7.0 to create a Notification Listener?
I am using this documentation [Notification Listener](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/design/shell/tiles-and-notifications/notification-listener).

I tried the documentation but can't find the file

*C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.5.1\Facades\System.Runtime.dll*

(Same file with .xml extension exists.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this exact error and I fixed it by installing [the Windows SDK](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/sdk-archive/) and then using it to edit the `.csproj` of your project and changing the `TargetFramework` to this:

```xml
<TargetFramework>net7.0-windows$([Microsoft.Build.Utilities.ToolLocationHelper]::GetLatestSDKTargetPlatformVersion('Windows', '10.0'))</TargetFramework>
```